# A problem with bounds of derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $b,f\in C^4(\overline\Omega)$ and $|u'_\epsilon(y)|\leq C\epsilon^{-1/2}$, $\epsilon$ is a small parameter. If I also know that $$u'_\epsilon(x)=u'_\epsilon(y)+\epsilon^{-1}\int_y^x(bu_\epsilon-f)(s)ds$$ How does this imply that $$|u'_\epsilon(x)|\leq C\epsilon^{-1/2}.$$ I am trying to follow the [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814390739) page 47.